# Can't connect to mySQL server which is running

Tags: server, mysql

I installed the latest mySQL Ubuntu distribution on my Ubuntu 13.04. The installation of the localhost server was succesfull and was working fine for a while. After creating a couple models (with no data in and saving them in my /home/... folder) on the server through mySQL Workbench I couldn't connect to the server anymore. The Workbench indicates that the server is running, but there is no connection to the server. When trying to access the server through terminal I get the following message:

```
root@simo-N150-N210-N220:~# mysql -u root -p mysql
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

After creating the two models on the server I also used the mdbtools to export some tabels from my old MS Access database (as CSV). This should not have any impact on mySQL server.

As far as I understand, the firewall hasn't blocked anything.

What can I do??

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This is *not* a connection error, it is an *authentication* error. The connection to MySQL is working well, otherwise you wouldn't get an "Access denied" error. Did you specify the right password for `root@localhost`? Just as a note: the `-p mysql` does not provide the password `mysql`, but selects the database `mysql`. If you did specify the right password interactively, then you want to check your system logs for errors or do a password recovery.

Answer (score 1):

You may be using the wrong command, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

That should work

Comment: maybe he's using password mysql , so it should be > mysql -u root -pmysql , -p(password)

Comment: @Qasim  The password shouldn't be in the command, it will be asked for, once the right command is entered.

Comment: no it will not ask the password if you use -ppassowrd , password right after -p ..., i am not saying anything about your answer ..your answer is the right one ...just updating you may be ..may be he is using password mysql ( and that should be -pmysql )

Comment: Sorry, same result:

Comment: root@simo-N150-N210-N220:~# mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: I reset the password and got it working, so far.root@simo-N150-N210-N220:~# dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5
mysql stop/waiting
mysql start/running, process 11664
root@simo-N150-N210-N220:~# mysql -u root test
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: root@simo-N150-N210-N220:~# netstat -ln | grep mysql
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     229161   /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
root@simo-N150-N210-N220:~# netstat -tap | grep mysql
tcp        0      0 localhost:mysql         *:*                     LISTEN      11664/mysqld    
root@simo-N150-N210-N220:~# mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor...
Your MySQL connection id is 37
Server version: 5.5.31-0ubuntu0.13.04.1 ...

mysql>